# Check for dot in string name

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm looking for a way so my php script can give a true or false when the string it searches in contains some characters after a dot in that exact order.

**For example:**

My string is: .htpassword

My script may only give true when it finds the string in my array containing a dot followed by some alphabetical characters and only in that order.

I've looked into the strpos() function but that doesn't fit my needs as I have some files containing characters with a dot after the characters.

*Valid match:*

- (dot)(followed by any character of the alphabet)

*Invalid matches:*

- (dot)(dot)(followed by any character of the alphabet)
- (some characters)(dot)(some characters)

**My script so far I've written:**

```
$arr_strings = $this->list_strings();

            $reg_expr_dot = '/\./';
            $match = array();

            foreach ($arr_strings as $string) {
                if (preg_match_all($reg_expr_dot, $file, $match) !== FALSE) {
                    echo "all strings: </br>";
                    echo $match[1] . "</br></br>";

                }
            }
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Kind regards

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=regular+expression+syntax

Comment: "containing a dot followed by some characters". what characters? non-dots? any characters? what about characters in front of the dot?

Comment: Show us an example of a valid match, and an example of an invalid match

Comment: @Dave your comment might have been really valuable if the search results contained the documentation of PHP's regex flavor. this way, you're suggesting that any regex reference would do.

Comment: It needs to be a dot followed by characters that can be in the a-z range. Doesn't matter if it is uppercase or lowercase.

Comment: @m.buettner for this usage, that's essentially true. The `[]` syntax is in the most popular variants.

Comment: but sure, here's a direct reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

Comment: @Dragon54 you are looking for [character classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) and [anchors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.anchors.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: (if I have well understand)

```
$arr_strings = $this->list_strings();

$reg_expr_dot = '/^\.[a-z]+$/i';

$intro = 'all strings: <br/>';
foreach ($arr_strings as $string) {
    if (preg_match($reg_expr_dot, $string, $match)) {
        echo $intro . $match[0];
        $intro = '<br/>';
    }
}
```

to be sure that an entire string is exactly as in your most crazy dreams, you can use anchors (at the begining `^` and at the end `$`) otherwhise your pattern could match a substring and return true. (You avoid to match `zzzz.htaccess` and `.htaccess#^..+=`)

The character class `[a-z]` contains uppercase letters too since I use the i modifier (case insensitive) at the end of the pattern.

Comment: Meta: [should regex answers contain an explanation? yes.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177757/are-answers-that-just-contain-a-regular-expression-pattern-really-good-answers)

Comment: @m.buettner: Wait a minute, I m not sure what is the question.

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution to my problem! Also thank you very much for explaining a bit more on the used regular expressions. Along with the documentation links I should get a better understanding of how regular expressions work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `/^\.[a-zA-Z]+/` - If there are additional criteria, let me know. I assumed '.' followed by any lowercase/uppercase character

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I fully understand the question but something like `/^\\.[a-zA-Z]+$/u` should suit your needs.

```
    $strings = $this->list_strings();
    $matches = array();

    foreach($strings as $string){
        if(preg_match("/^\\.[a-zA-Z]+$/u", $string)){
            $matches[] = $string;
        }
    }

    echo "all strings: </br>";

    foreach($matches as $match){
        echo $match."</br>"; 
    }
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: If you were using single-quotes you wouldn't need to double up any backslashes.